# making wordpress content look better

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have a wordpress site in development, it displays a lot of data in that are arranged in tables. The problem with this is they don't look very nice, i have empty cells if some of that days data doesn't go as far as the other and just you general problems with using tables on websites.

I'd like to be able to make the design look a bit better and maybe get away from the restrictions of using table design but i have no idea where to look or where to start?

I was thinking of making my own CSS for the body content, but i'd need to have that as default in the editor and make it so that others can just add the values to the new design. Can this be done? Maybe i could get some sort of plugin?

Thanks for the help.

This is a good example of how things are at the moment, i want to make this a bit better looking and a bit more up to date looking as well.

http://www.tradeitsafe.com/?page_id=64

Comment: can you link to the site in question?

Comment: It's on my local machine at the moment. @spaceranger

Comment: I'll try and get it online now. @spaceranger

Comment: Okay i've added a link to the question @spaceranger

Comment: you simply don't have enough space. you'll have to break the tables into smaller parts. Or make a other design choise. Like make is appear in a (full screen) light box

Comment: This is a very general question, unclear what specific and objective answers can be given (and [SO] is certainly not for web (visual) design questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn some css http://www.w3schools.com/css/ Create the css around some dummy content. Then depending how you have built the site, you can create a template for that type of page, post, post_type (for example for page, it might be page-id.php, or page-tables.php and put that into your theme template. You need to copy the code from the page.php file in your theme into that new template file first, then alter the code, to include your newly designed css and insert the content using wordpress function codex for example:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="date"><?php the_date ?></div>
        <div class="content"><?php the_content ?></div>
        <div class="total"><?php field('the_total')?> </div>
</div>
```

hope that helps.